# Wind rose diagram plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, weibull

I am currently trying to plot in matlab a wind rose diagram with data wind velocities and directions for a given period.
The main program is such that after plotting several plots on the Weibull distribution, it calls another matlab program to produce a wind rose.

The wind rose program is essentially here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47248-wind-rose

and the main program is mainly based on https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41996-computing-weibull-distribution-parameters-from-a-wind-speed-time-series?focused=3786165&tab=function

I've been working yesterday on a very old matlab edition and I had serious problems with making the code run.
Today with Octave in a Ubuntu machine and after some efforts I managed to get a result with a minor problem: the wind rose did not had all the information it should have.

I run the program in a new version of matlab and then I got the following message:

```
Error using WindRose (line 244)
 is not a valid property for WindRose function.
Error in octavetestoforiginalprogram (line 184)
[figure_handle,count,speeds,directions,Table] = WindRose(dir,vel,Options);
```

How can the program run in Octave and now produces such an error, I don't understand.

Does anyone have an idea of what this error means?

Note: I am posting the entire code below if anyone wants to read it:

```
%% EXTRACT AND PLOT RAW DATA

% Extract wind speed data from a file
v = xlsread('1981-1985_timeseries.xlsx');

% Plot the measured wind speed
plot(v)
title('Wind speed time series');
xlabel('Measurement #');
ylabel('Wind speed [m/s]');





%% PROCESS DATA

% Remove nil speed data (to avoid infeasible solutions in the following)
v(find(v==0)) = [];
% Extract the unique values occuring in the series
uniqueVals = unique(v);
uniqueVals(isnan(uniqueVals))=[];

% Get the number of unique values
nbUniqueVals = length(uniqueVals);

% Find the number of occurences of each unique wind speed value
for i=1:nbUniqueVals
    nbOcc = v(find(v==uniqueVals(i)));
    N(i) = length(nbOcc);
end

% Get the total number of measurements
nbMeas = sum(N);

% To take into account the measurement resolution
% (i.e., a measured wind speed of 2.0 m/s may actually correspond to a
% real wind speed of 2.05 or 1.98 m/s), compute the delta vector which
% contains the difference between two consecutive unique values
delta(1) = uniqueVals(1);
for i=2:nbUniqueVals
    delta(i) = uniqueVals(i) - uniqueVals(i-1);
end

% Get the frequency of occurence of each unique value
for i=1:nbUniqueVals
    prob(i) = N(i)/(nbMeas*delta(i));
end



% Get the cumulated frequency
freq = 0;
for i=1:nbUniqueVals
    freq = prob(i)*delta(i) + freq;
    cumFreq(i) = freq;
end


%% PLOT THE RESULTING DISTRIBUTION

% Plot the distribution
figure
subplot(2,1,1);
pp=plot(uniqueVals,prob)
title('Distribution extracted from the time series');
xlabel('Wind speed [m/s]');
ylabel('Probability');

% Plot the cumulative distribution
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(uniqueVals,cumFreq)
title('Cumulative distribution extracted from the time series');
xlabel('Wind speed [m/s]');
ylabel('Cumulative probability');


%% EXTRACT THE PARAMETERS USING A GRAPHICAL METHOD

% See the following references for more explanations:
% - Akdag, S.A. and Dinler, A., A new method to estimate Weibull parameters
% for wind energy applications, Energy Conversion and Management,
% 50 :7 1761�1766, 2009
% - Seguro, J.V. and Lambert, T.W., Modern estimation of the parameters of
% the Weibull wind speed distribution for wind energy analysis, Journal of
% Wind Engineering and Industrial Aerodynamics, 85 :1 75�84, 2000


% Linearize distributions (see papers)
ln = log(uniqueVals);
lnln = log(-log(1-cumFreq));

% Check wether the vectors contain inifinite values, if so, remove them
test = isinf(lnln);
for i=1:nbUniqueVals
    if (test(i)==1)
        ln(i)= [];
        lnln(i)= [];
    end
end

% Extract the line parameters (y=ax+b) using the polyfit function
params = polyfit(ln,lnln',1);
a = params(1);
b = params(2);
y=a*ln+b;

% Compare the linealized curve and its fitted line
figure
plot(ln,y,'b',ln,lnln,'r')
title('Linearized curve and fitted line comparison');
xlabel('x = ln(v)');
ylabel('y = ln(-ln(1-cumFreq(v)))');

% Extract the Weibull parameters c and k
k = a
c = exp(-b/a)


%% CHECK RESULTS

% Define the cumulative Weibull probability density function
% F(V) = 1-exp(-((v/c)^k)) = 1-exp(-a2), with a1 = v/c, a2 = (v/c)^k
a1 = uniqueVals/c;
a2 = a1.^k;
cumDensityFunc = 1-exp(-a2); 

% Define the Weibull probability density function
%f(v)=k/c*(v/c)^(k-1)*exp(-((v/c)^k))=k2*a3.*exp(-a2), 
% with  k2 = k/c, a3 = (v/c)^(k-1)
k1 = k-1;
a3 = a1.^k1;
k2 = k/c;
densityFunc = k2*a3.*exp(-a2);  

% Plot and compare the obtained Weibull distribution with the frequency plot
figure
subplot(2,2,1);
pp=plot(uniqueVals,prob,'.',uniqueVals,densityFunc, 'r')
title('Weibull probability density function');
xlabel('v');
ylabel('f(v)');

subplot(2,2,3)
h=hist(v);
title('Wind speed time series');
xlabel('Measurement #');
ylabel('Wind speed [m/s]');
h=h/(sum(h)*10);
bar(h)

% Same for the cumulative distribution
subplot(2,2,2);
plot(uniqueVals,cumFreq,'.',uniqueVals,cumDensityFunc, 'r')
title('Cumulative Weibull probability density function');
xlabel('v');
ylabel('F(V)');


%inner
figure
hold on
pp=plot(uniqueVals,prob,'.',uniqueVals,densityFunc, 'r')
title('Weibull probability density function');
xlabel('v');
ylabel('f(v)');

bar(h)

hold off

%inner



%rose

w=xlsread('rose.xlsx');
dir=w(:,2)*10;
vel=w(:,1);

Options = {'anglenorth','FreqLabelAngle',0,'angleeast','FreqLabelAngle',90,'labels',{'N (0)','S (180)','E (90)','W (270)'},'freqlabelangle',45,'nDirections',20,'nFreq',25,'LegendType',1};
[figure_handle,count,speeds,directions,Table] = WindRose(dir,vel,Options);

close all; clear Options;
```

Comment: Note that all the plots are reproduced from the newer version of matlab, I just have a problem with taking the wind rose diagram. Thank you all.

Comment: If I check the windrose.m , it seems to me there is something going on with @ operator in arrayfun? Is something like this possible?

Comment: I tried it under Matlab 2017 and it works fine with the default examples. It could depend by your data.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Well, my data give me all the other plots... and as far as I can see, they are just vectors- if you run it you 've seen it. Is there something particular you have in mind? Or, could it be a package missing? Thank you.

Comment: It seems like one of your arguments is an empty string...

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Do you think there could be a semantic mistake at : dir=w(:,2)*10;
vel=w(:,1);

Comment: Nope, the problem must be searched within the options in my opinion. As far as I remember from reading the script guide, they must either be name-value pairs or organized into a struct object.

Comment: Ok, I found your error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick read of the script documentation, here is what I found concerning the creation of the `windrose` plot:

```
% With options in a cell array:
Options = {'anglenorth',0,'angleeast',90,'labels',{'N (0°)','S (180°)','E (90°)','W (270°)'},'freqlabelangle',45};
[figure_handle,count,speeds,directions,Table] = WindRose(dir,spd,Options);

% With options in a structure:
Options.AngleNorth     = 0;
Options.AngleEast      = 90;
Options.Labels         = {'N (0°)','S (180°)','E (90°)','W (270°)'};
Options.FreqLabelAngle = 45;
[figure_handle,count,speeds,directions,Table] = WindRose(dir,spd,Options);
close all;

% Usual calling:
[figure_handle,count,speeds,directions,Table] = WindRose(dir,spd,'anglenorth',0,'angleeast',90,'labels',{'N (0°)','S (180°)','E (90°)','W (270°)'},'freqlabelangle',45);
```

Your error is:

```
Error using WindRose (line 244)
 is not a valid property for WindRose function.

Error in octavetestoforiginalprogram (line 184)
[figure_handle,count,speeds,directions,Table] = WindRose(dir,vel,Options);
```

And it is being produced within the routine that undertakes option arguments sanitization. Since options must be provided in the form of name-value pairs... it seems that the script is detecting a mismatching number of elements and one or more names with a missing value. And here they are:

> Options =
>   {**'anglenorth'**,'FreqLabelAngle',0,**'angleeast'**,'FreqLabelAngle',90,'labels',{'N
>   (0)','S (180)','E (90)','W
>   (270)'},'freqlabelangle',45,'nDirections',20,'nFreq',25,'LegendType',1};

The two properties marked with a bold font have no value associated to them (unlike the examples in the tutorial) and this probably messes up the whole parametrization process. Probably, the first option being extracted is `anglenorth = FreqLabelAngle`, which is not correct.

Comment: Well, if that's the problem( and somehow Octave got around it) I can't thank you enough. Unfortunately I don't have access to matlab right now, to verify your claim, but it seems reasonable to believe you are correct and that this is in fact the root of the error. I will check the code in about 9-10 hours, and I will get back at you. But again, thank you for all your effort here.

Comment: It runs. Now I just have to figure how to produce the desired result. Again, thank you very much; you consideration has been great.